# Read and write a single cell in excel using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlwings

I am looking to replace the database (SQL)(around 50,000*50 rows*columns) for my app with excel. I need to update a single cell in excel without loading the whole workbook and then saving it again (I am using Openpyxl) as it is computationally very expensive. I need an alternative that will help me save execution time.

I have tried excel APIs like xlwings but need an alternative to APIs

Comment: If the data you are planning to replace will be on only 1 worksheet of the workbook. You can use 'pandas' to connect to your SQL DB export the data to a DataFrame (in memory). Make the conditional change and write the DataFrame to excel file. Pandas is very useful in such cases

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so I will "answer". Why would you replace a database with Excel? Sounds crazy to me. There are plenty of other persistent storage file systems out there to use, pickle, HD5, pyarrow stuff, csv, etc.. I used the feather format for a while, super fast and pandas can use it natively.